# copy a const char* into array of char (facing a bug)

Tags: c

I have following method

```
static void setName(const char* str, char buf[16])
{
    int sz = MIN(strlen(str), 16);
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) buf[i] = str[i];
    buf[sz] = 0;
}


int main()
{
   const char* string1 = "I am getting bug for this long string greater than 16 lenght);
   char mbuf[16];
   setName(string,mybuf)
   // if I use buf in my code it is leading to spurious characters since length is greater than 16 .
```

Please let me know what is the correct way to code above if the restriction for buf length is 16 in method static void setName(const char* str, char buf[16])

Comment: You copy 15 characters and set the 16th character to the NUL character?

Comment: You need to consider a trailing `'\0'` for the result at `buf[15]`.

Comment: Though better to just use `strncpy`.

Comment: `MIN(..., 16)` should be `MIN(..., 15)`

Comment: Why it is leading to junk characters . Can some one tell me in detail

Comment: As others have commented, the null write is out-of-bounds.  UB.  Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing an array as argument, array decays into the pointer of FIRST element of array. One must define a rule, to let the method know the number of elements.

You declare `char mbuf[16]`, you pass it to `setName()`, `setName()` will not get `char[]`, but will get `char*` instead.

So, the declaration should be

```
static void setName(const char* str, char* buf)
```

Next, `char mbuf[16]` can only store 15 chars, because the last char has to be 'null terminator', which is '\0'. Otherwise, the following situation will occur:

> // if I use buf in my code it is leading to spurious characters since length is greater than 16 .

Perhaps this will help you understand:

```
char str[] = "foobar"; // = {'f','o','o','b','a','r','\0'};
```

So the code should be

```
static void setName(const char* str, char* buf)
{
    int sz = MIN(strlen(str), 15); // not 16
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) buf[i] = str[i];
    buf[sz] = '\0'; // assert that you're assigning 'null terminator'
}
```

Also, I would recommend you not to reinvent the wheel, why don't use `strncpy` instead?

```
char mbuf[16];
strncpy(mbuf, "12345678901234567890", 15);
```

Comment: Can a say static void setName(const char* str, char* buf)
{
    int sz = MIN(strlen(str), 16); // not 16
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) buf[i] = str[i];
    buf[sz] = '\0'; // assert that you're assigning 'null terminator'
}  is a memory corruption

Comment: @TechEnthusiast Memory corruption?? What do you mean?

Comment: There are reasons to be cautious about using `strncpy()`, such as the fact that it null-pads to full length (given: char dst[20480]; strncpy(dst, sizeof(dst), arg);` where `arg` points to a 79-character string, `strncpy()` will write 20400 null bytes to `dst`).  Also (assuming `char buf[16];`), `strncpy(buf, 15, longer_than_15_string)` does ***not** null terminate `buf`; you have to write `buf[15] = '\0';` explicitly to be sure of null termination.

Comment: Memory corruption means we are writing  characters more than the param length , may be array out of bound .

Comment: Also one more question does buf[sz] = 0; in above code of setName is same buf[sz] = '\0';  i.e putting null terminator in buf

Comment: Also what is name of the term if we put  buf[sz] = 0 when the str length is greater than 16 , is it Array out of bound

Comment: @TechEnthusiast `'\0'` can be considered as same with `0`, it is just that `'\0'` make your intent clear ("I'm using this as null character and I know it"). As for writing more than param length, it shouldn't happen unless you specify the wrong length in `strncpy()`.

Comment: You're using `MIN` macro, isn't it? The `sz` never exceed 15 if `sz = MIN(strlen(str), 15);`... Since your char array has 16 elements, even if strlen is 32, `sz` will still be 15, and `str[sz]` refers to the 16th char, so there's no out of bound here...

Comment: Thanks but I was asking is there  any array bound write in following code for case when we have length of str is 142                                                                                     static void setName(const char* str, char buf[16])
    {
    int sz = MIN(strlen(str), 16);
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) buf[i] = str[i];
    buf[sz] = 0;
   }

Answer (score 0):

The following code passes the size of the memory allocated to the buffer, to the setName function.
That way the setName function can ensure that it does not write outside the allocated memory.
Inside the function either a `for` loop or `strncpy` can be used. Both will be controlled by the size parameter `sz` and both will require that a null terminator character is placed after the copied characters. Again, `sz` will ensure that the null terminator is written within the memory allocated to the buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void setName(const char *str, char *buf, int sz);

int main()
{
    const int a_sz = 16;
    char* string = "This bit is OK!! but any more than 15 characters are dropped";

    /* allocate memory for a buffer & test successful allocation*/
    char *mbuf = malloc(a_sz);
    if (mbuf == NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory!\n");
        return(1);
    }

    /* call function and pass size of buffer */
    setName(string, mbuf, a_sz);
    /* print resulting buffer contents */
    printf("%s\n", mbuf); // printed: This bit is OK!

    /* free the memory allocated to the buffer */
    free(mbuf);
    return(0);
}

static void setName(const char *str, char *buf, int sz)
{
    int i;

    /* size of string or max 15 */
    if (strlen(str) > sz - 1) {
        sz--;
    } else {
        sz = strlen(str);
    }

    /* copy a maximum of 15 characters into buffer (0 to 14) */
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) buf[i] = str[i];
    /* null terminate the string - won't be more than buf[15]) */
    buf[i] = '\0';
}
```

Changing one value `const int a_sz` allows different numbers of characters to be copied. There is no 'hard coding' of the size in the function, so reducing the risk of errors if the code is modified later on.

I replaced MIN with a simple `if ... else` structure so that I could test the code.